SendOrPostCallback does not run in the same thread when calling SynchronizationContext.Post()
For my question I have prepared a C# Fiddle and when you click "Run" there few times, you will see the exception in the log.
If you compile and run my code listed below in Visual Studio 2022 or VS Code, then more details are shown:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConcurrentOperationsNotSupported()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value)
   at SyncContextTest.PlayloadAccumulationHandler.AddCallback(Object state) in PlayloadAccumulationHandler.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext`1.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

Here is my simple test case -
In Program.cs I create 100 threads and then make them call handler.Add():
class Program
{
    private const int NUM_THREADS = 100;
    private static PayloadAccumulationHandler handler = new();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new(RunMe);
        Thread[] threads = Enumerable.Range(0, NUM_THREADS)
            .Select(_ => new Thread(ts))
            .ToArray();

        foreach (Thread t in threads)
        {
            t.Start();
        }

        foreach (Thread t in threads)
        {
            t.Join();
        }
    }

    private static void RunMe()
    {
        int threadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
        handler.Add("microsoft", "de", (uint)(threadId % 3));
    }
}

And in the PayloadAccumulationHandler.cs I try to use SynchronizationContext.Post():
public class PayloadAccumulationHandler
{
    private static readonly SynchronizationContext SyncContextTest = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();

    private static Dictionary<string, uint> dict = [];

    public void Add(string brand, string country, uint useCaseId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Add({brand}, {country}, {useCaseId})");
        string key = $"{brand}/{country}/{useCaseId}";
        SyncContextTest.Post(AddCallback, key);
    }

    public void AddCallback(object? state)
    {
        int threadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;

        if (state is string key)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"AddCallback: {threadId} {key}");

            if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out uint value))
            {
                dict[key] = value + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dict[key] = 1; // throws System.InvalidOperationException!
            }
        }
    }
}

The dict is of type Dictionary and not ConcurrentDictionary on purpose - because I wanted to verify that the code in AddCallback method runs in the same thread.
But it is not! Am I doing something wrong or maybe assuming something wrong?
I was expecting SynchronizationContext.Post() to act similar to Android handlers, where you post callbacks at the handler and it ensures that their code runs on the same thread.
Also, I have noticed that SynchronizationContext.Current is null and the new SynchronizationContext() is run in my console app. Should I somehow tell/configure that new instance to use a single thread for executing the callbacks?

That is entirely normal.  To get back to the same thread you need a sync provider.  The kind that a Winforms, UWP, Maui or WPF app has.  They have the plumbing (a dispatcher, fed by Application.Run) that can run code on the main thread as needed.  More here

Ah! And do you think there is a default implementation available for ASP.Net Core app (.Net 8) or should I write a custom one for my real web app (not the test case here)?

You start on a thread with no specific properties (such as UI), so every thread is as good as the one it is currently running on. "The SynchronizationContext class is a base class that provides a free-threaded context with no synchronization". So, basically, it does nothing. What are you trying to achieve? Use a ConcurrentDictionary if you want to access the dictionary from multiple threads.

Ok, a base class with no sync, that is why... I am trying to collect some stats (number of bytes per brand/country) in an ASP.Net Core application using singletons per DI. I think ConcurrentDictionary is not good enough, because I have to atomically increment the existing values in it (because another thread can try to access the same value I am trying to increment). That is why I thought there could be a "handler" which I could "ask" to run code on the same thread...

I suggest not to implement your own synchronization context. It's even hard for Steven Cleary or Stephen Toub (one of them; I always mix them up).

I also don't see how synchronizing 100 threads to a single thread is any faster than using a ConcurrentDictionary, but I never benchmarked that, so, yeah, maybe.

No I was just trying to create a test case simulating my real ASP.Net Core app...

Related: Why the default SynchronizationContext is not captured in a Console App? and also Single-threaded async/await in C# console app.
